# Enable @mention in discussions board

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016

I am using SharePoint server 2016, I created a new discussion board list,

My question is 
How can mention someone or group in the discussion board post/comment ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could deactivate and activate “Community Site Feature” on the site.

Then you could enable @mention in discussions board like the picture below.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you have just added a discussion board to team site or publishing site you will need to browse to `Site settings` and then `Site features` and activate the `Community Site Features`
 Feature.